# Asp.net Razor Pages How to Route to another folder

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am currently in my home page, and I want to route to the index page of the GenericDrugs folder,
How do I go about this.

My Folder structure looks like this

[image]

In my layout.cshtml, I have this line of code

```
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/GenericDrugs/Index">Generic Drugs Index Page</a>
   </li>
```

But for some reason, whenever I click on the link, I do not reroute to the GenericDrugs index page.
However, if I were to type the link directly into the search bar it works.

Comment: If it's not taking you where to go, what URL does it take you to? And what is the full URL of the address you're able to type directly in the browser in order to get there?

Comment: @mason the page simply refreshes and stays in thesame URL. The home page URL is "https://localhost:7088/", I want to go to "https://localhost:7088/GenericDrugs/Index"

Comment: Are you sure it just refreshes? Are you sure it doesn't go to the other page and get redirected back for some reason? They would appear the same to the casual observer. Look at your browser's network tab and pay careful attention to the requests and responses. You may need to tell it to preserve HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks, you led me to the right path. The beginning of my index page in the GenericDrugs/Index file had the "@page "{DrugSearch}"  once i took out the "{drugsearch}" It worked just fine. Thank you very much Mr. Mason